# System.out.print the winning line only

Tags: java, while-loop, duplicates, system.out

I have a java lottery game assignment and where I am running a while loop to prevent duplication of numbers in the result.
I am getting a list of numbers with no duplicates, however the `System.out.print` is returning all lines until I get the final one with no duplicates. Is there a way to only print the final "winning" line?

Code below

```java
while (numCount<=9) {
  int randNumber = rand.nextInt(99)+1;
  if (results[0] == randNumber || results[1] == randNumber || results[2] == randNumber || results[3] == randNumber ||
        results[4] == randNumber || results[5] == randNumber || results[6] == randNumber || results[7] == randNumber 
        || results[8] == randNumber || results[9] == randNumber) {
    
  } else {
    Array.setInt(results, numCount, randNumber);
    numCount++;
  }
    
  System.out.print("The Lottery Numbers are: ");
    
  for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
      //add a 0 in front of the number is it's less that 10
    if (results[i] <10) {
      System.out.print("0"+results[i]+" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: bring your print for loop out of while loop.

Comment: You may substitute the results array by `Set<Integer>` and apply [contains](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this simpler, relying on the fact that a `Set` does not have duplicate objects in it.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    Set<Integer> winningNumbers = new HashSet<>();

    while (winningNumbers.size() < 9) {
        int randNumber = rand.nextInt(99) + 1;
        winningNumbers.add(randNumber);
    }

    System.out.print("The Lottery Numbers are: ");
    for (Integer number : winningNumbers) {
        //add a 0 in front of the number is it's less that 10
        if (number < 10) {
            System.out.print("0" + number + " ");
        } else {
            System.out.print(number + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

You can even simplify the way you are printing the numbers, relying on `printf()` and `%02d`, which means that 0 paddings are used being the maximum width of the printed numbers 2:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    Set<Integer> winningNumbers = new HashSet<>();

    while (winningNumbers.size() < 9) {
        int randNumber = rand.nextInt(99) + 1;
        winningNumbers.add(randNumber);
    }

    System.out.print("The Lottery Numbers are: ");
    System.out.printf("%02d %02d %02d %02d %02d %02d %02d %02d %02d", winningNumbers.toArray());
}
```

---

In your code, just move the line `System.out.print("The Lottery Numbers are: ");` to before the while loop and the loop `for (int i=0; i<10; i++)` to after the while loop as follows:

```java
System.out.print("The Lottery Numbers are: ");
while (numCount<=9) {
    int randNumber = rand.nextInt(99)+1;
    if (results[0] == randNumber || results[1] == randNumber || results[2] == randNumber || results[3] == randNumber ||
            results[4] == randNumber || results[5] == randNumber || results[6] == randNumber || results[7] == randNumber
            || results[8] == randNumber || results[9] == randNumber) {
        
    } else {
        Array.setInt(results, numCount, randNumber);
        numCount++;
    }
}

for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    //add a 0 in front of the number is it's less that 10
    if (results[i] <10) {
        System.out.print("0"+results[i]+" ");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! In class, we haven't used HashSet or Formatter yet and we were specifically told not to use formatter in this assignment. I've tried what you've suggested and it worked so I'll keep that in mind for future reference.

Comment: When I do it my way, using the classes he showed I get the results below                                    

The Sum of the winning numbers is: 449The Lottery Numbers are: 91 88 74 12 95 66 23 56 00 00 
The Sum of the winning numbers is: 505The Lottery Numbers are: 91 88 74 12 95 66 23 56 67 00 
The Sum of the winning numbers is: 572The Lottery Numbers are: 91 88 74 12 95 66 23 56 67 00 
The Sum of the winning numbers is: 572The Lottery Numbers are: 91 88 74 12 95 66 23 56 67 15 
The Sum of the winning numbers is: 587

Comment: I've updated my answer with your code with the fixes you need to do to avoid duplicated lines in the output. Please check it ;) Thanks!

Comment: I am glad I was able to help! ;)